# BIM360 Project's Service Type undocumented

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

On GET projects from BIM360, `service_types`property contains services no documented.

Making a GET request to BIM360 Projects (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-GET/), the `service_types` returns additional values than those documented on https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/overview/parameters/#service-type

```
{
    "id": "{PROJECT_ID}",
    "account_id": "{ACCOUNT_ID}",
    "name": "Sample Project",
    "start_date": "2019-09-25",
    "end_date": "2019-10-25",
    "value": null,
    "currency": null,
    "status": "active",
    "job_number": null,
    "address_line_1": null,
    "address_line_2": null,
    "city": null,
    "state_or_province": null,
    "postal_code": null,
    "country": "United States",
    "business_unit_id": null,
    "created_at": "2019-09-25T14:26:04.092Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-10-04T16:44:25.271Z",
    "project_type": "Demonstration Project",
    "timezone": null,
    "language": "en",
    "construction_type": null,
    "contract_type": null,
    "last_sign_in": "2019-10-04T16:44:25.000Z",
    "service_types": "doc_manager,insight,admin"
}
```

According to the documentation, only `field`, `glue`, `schedule`, `plan` and `doc_manager`are expected.

Comment: Hey Alavaro, let me look into this. To me it sounds the documentation could be out of date and we need to push an update to it. Give me some time to check with the Team.

Answer (score 0):

So at the moment the situation is that those services are not properly documented since they are not fully supported yet. They are actively working in making this services better and documented properly. There is an improvement process being worked on this quarter. Check back with us in a near future, a good structure and improvement to the bim360 service is coming. thank you for reaching out.